# How to call std::chrono::is_am with a time_point?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

[C++20 adds these free functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.12) to `namespace std::chrono`:

> `constexpr bool is_am(const hours& h) noexcept;`

> *Returns:* `0h <= h && h <= 11h`.

> `constexpr bool is_pm(const hours& h) noexcept;`

> *Returns:* `12h <= h && h <= 23h`.

But I don't have `hours`.  I have a `std::chrono::time_point`.  How can I find out if my `time_point` is am or pm?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't.  For example `steady_clock::time_point` has no relationship whatsoever to human created times, dates or calendars.  It is like a stopwatch.  So it would be senseless to try to find out if a `steady_clock::time_point` is am or pm.

However it does make sense for those `time_point`s associated with `system_clock` (UTC, aka `std::chrono::sys_time<Duration>`), and those associated with a local time (`std::chrono::local_time<Duration>`).

To see how to do this, it is instructive to form 4 overloads:

```
template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_am(std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp);

template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_am(std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp);

template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_pm(std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp);

template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_pm(std::chrono::local_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp);
```

However, all of these are very similar.  So I'll just show how to do the first.  And to derive the first, it is instructive to first break it into tiny bits at a time.  But in the end, it will wrap up into one line of code.

```
template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_am(std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tpd = floor<days>(tp);
    auto tod = tp - tpd;
    auto h = floor<hours>(tod);
    return is_am(h);
}
```

- It is convenient to issue a function-local using directive to cut down on the verbosity of having `std::chrono::` sprinkled all over the place.  If you prefer the sprinkling, skip the using directive.
- First start the process of deconstructing the `time_point` into fields such as {y, m, d, H, M, S}.  Though only the hours field is really needed.  The first step in this to extract the date as a days-precision `time_point`, labeled `tpd` above.
- Next, find the time-of-day (`tod`). It is just the "date_time - date".
- The hours can be extracted from the time-of-day using the `floor` function again.
- Finally just return `is_am` on the extracted hours.

This can be more concisely wrapped up as just:

```
template <class Rep, class Ratio>
bool
is_am(std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Ratio>> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return is_am(floor<hours>(tp - floor<days>(tp)));
}
```

The exact same implementation can be used for the `local_time` overload.  And when you make the `is_pm` overloads, just remember to switch out `is_am` for `is_pm` in the definitions.

These can be called like this:

```
cout << is_am(system_clock::now()) << '\n';
cout << is_am(current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
cout << is_pm(system_clock::now()) << '\n';
cout << is_pm(current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now())) << '\n';
```